# JavaScript / Node.js / Express.js : HTTP Route Filtering for Completion Status from Data Object --> Test Spec

Tags: javascript, express, filter, specifications

I'm using Node.js and Express.  I'm trying to setup a router HTTP request.

The Test spec is as follows:

```
describe("query filtering (?key=value)", function() {
      beforeEach(function() {
        todos.add("billy", { content: "learn about req.query" });
        todos.complete("billy", 0);
        todos.add("billy", { content: "enable requests for specific todos" });
      });
```

I have functions that the above test spec is calling.  The above test spec returns:

```
{ billy:
   [ { content: 'learn about req.query', complete: true },
     { content: 'enable requests for specific todos',
       complete: false } ] }
```

The remaining test spec is:

```
it("GET can get just the completed tasks", function() {
        return supertest
          .get("/users/billy/tasks?status=complete")
          .expect(200)
          .expect("Content-Type", /json/)
          .expect(function(res) {
            expect(res.body).to.have.length(1);
            expect(res.body[0].content).to.equal("learn about req.query");
          });
      });
```

Below is the code I used to try and pass the test spec:

```
// GET can get just the completed tasks
router.get("/users/:name/tasks?status=complete", (req, res, next) => {
  let name = req.params.name;

  // req.query would yield {status: complete}
  if (req.query.status === "complete") {
    const completedTasks = todos
      .list(name)
      .filter(todoTask => todoTask.complete === true);
    res.send(completedTasks);
  }
});
```

But it did not pass Error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "it did not pass" is hardly enough information...

Comment: true, I added more detail

Comment: 1. which line in this code triggers the error? (you should be able to see stacktrace). 2. are you using a middleware? I can assure you that this is not all the code which is executed, because this error means you are calling `res.send` twice on the same `res`